# How to interpret symbolized crash reports?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, crittercism

This is the crash report i have got from crittercism.

```
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x3a0b3054 <redacted>
1     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x3a0b2f9b <redacted>
2     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x3a0b2f67 <redacted>
3     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x3a0b261b <redacted>
4     myApp                         0x000fa697 -[LBYouTubePlayerController   _didSuccessfullyExtractYouTubeURL:] (LBYouTubePlayerController.m:83)
5     myApp                         0x000fa72d -[LBYouTubePlayerController youTubeExtractor:didSuccessfullyExtractYouTubeURL:] (LBYouTubePlayerController.m:101)
6     myApp                             0x000fa073 -[LBYouTubeExtractor _didSuccessfullyExtractYouTubeURL:] (LBYouTubeExtractor.m:224)
7     myApp                             0x000fa2bf -[LBYouTubeExtractor connectionDidFinishLoading:] (LBYouTubeExtractor.m:272)
8     myApp                             0x00114137 __52-[CRNetworkMonitor swizzleDidFinishLoadingForClass:]_block_invoke210 + 27
9     Foundation                            0x32b476fd <redacted>
10   Foundation                             0x32a871f9 <redacted>
11   Foundation                             0x32a87115 <redacted>
12   CFNetwork                              0x31ee945f <redacted>
13   CFNetwork                              0x31ee8b43 <redacted>
14   CFNetwork                              0x31f10fcb <redacted>
15   CoreFoundation                         0x3215274d CFArrayApplyFunction
16   CFNetwork                              0x31f1142b <redacted>
17   CFNetwork                              0x31e7503d <redacted>
18   CoreFoundation                         0x321e1683 <redacted>
19   CoreFoundation                         0x321e0f7f <redacted>
20   CoreFoundation                         0x321dfcb7 <redacted>
21   CoreFoundation                         0x32152ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific
22   CoreFoundation                         0x32152d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode
23   GraphicsServices                       0x35d1e2eb GSEventRunModal
24   UIKit                                  0x34068301 UIApplicationMain
25   myApp                          0x000ef9e7 main (main.m:16)
```

I cant figure out what had happened.

These are the file [LBYouTubePlayerController.m](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wxuos9j7hz6b6n/LBYouTubePlayerController.m)

and

[LBYouTubeExtractor.m](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdh5rysepd9fsxh/LBYouTubeExtractor.m)

Comment: just drag it to your xcode organiser tab . Desymbolization will happen and let you know which method leads to crash

Comment: dysymbolification will happen only if u have the .dsym file for the generated .ipa

Comment: Please post the full crash report and not just that snipped. Important information is missing to interpret it.

Comment: did you fix this problem ? i have the same problem but with AFNetworking. i have no idea where CRNetworkMonitor comes from.

Comment: @AndyJacobs CRNetworkMonitor is a class from Crittercism SDK

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this line:

```
8     myApp                             0x00114137 __52-[CRNetworkMonitor swizzleDidFinishLoadingForClass:]_block_invoke210 + 27
```

It's bug in **Crittercism** library!
This bug was fixed in v. 4.3.2 SDK.

More info here:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1853